Оптимизировать SQL запрос с подсчетом по нескольким периодам
Есть postgresql и таблица с идентификатором факта Fact_id и датой его создания Created_at типа:



Fact_id
Created_at




5770
2024-12-20 15:55:54


5775
2024-12-20 10:52:22


6122
2024-12-25 10:10:09


6235
2024-12-21 12:23:58


5775
2024-12-25 18:17:47


6122
2024-12-23 18:53:15


5770
2024-12-22 14:22:16


6122
2024-12-26 14:16:38



Мне нужно посчитать, сколько Fact_id было создано за последниt сутки, за сутки до этого, и за двое суток до. Но в результирующей таблице отразить значения только в том случае, если Fact_id был создан за последние сутки.
Меня хватило на вложенный запрос:
select fact_id, int_1, int_2, int_3
from (select fact_id,
     COUNT(case when created_at >= (now() - interval '1 day') then 1 end) as int_1,
     COUNT(case when created_at between (now() - interval '1 day') and (now() - interval '2 day') then 1 end) as int_2,
     COUNT(case when created_at between (now() - interval '2 day') and (now() - interval '3 day') then 1 end) as int_3
     from table
     where created_at >= (now() - interval '3 day')
     group by fact_id) as d
where int_1 > 0

В итоге я получаю таблицу:



Fact_id
int_1
int_2
int_3




6122
1
1
0



Можно ли как-то оптимизировать, сократить код, чтобы получить такой же результат? Отдельно смущает заданные практически вручную периоды в условиях для COUNT.

Внешний запрос не нужен - есть же HAVING... А ещё Вы неправильно считаете, если какой-то штамп имеет 00:00:00 (вернее, совпадает с текущим временем), он будет посчитан дважды. Замените BETWEEN на два неравенства, сверху строгое, снизу нет. Отдельно смущает заданные практически вручную периоды в условиях для COUNT. Сформируйте из них статическую таблицу и используйте в качестве критерия.

Наброски алгоритма: fiddle

По дате мне нельзя, надо именно последние 24 часа. Но смысл понятен, спасибо. Особенно рекурсия заинтересовала. И за замечание по BETWEEN отдельная благодарность.

Посмотрите пример с CROSSTAB
В пример данных я добавил строки для рассмотрения разных случаев и перевел даты на сутки вперёд, чтобы получить нужные сегодня, вчера и т.д.
Сперва вычислим день(dd) от сегодня (назад) для каждой строки.
Это значение будем использовать для группировки (подсчета количества) строк.
select *
  ,extract('day' from now()-created_at)dd
from logs




fact_id
created_at
dd




5770
2024-12-21 15:55:54
6


5775
2024-12-21 10:52:22
6


6122
2024-12-26 10:10:09
1


6235
2024-12-22 12:23:58
5


5775
2024-12-26 18:17:47
0


6122
2024-12-24 18:53:15
2


5770
2024-12-23 14:22:16
4


6122
2024-12-27 14:16:38
0


9990
2024-12-25 14:16:38
2



После группировки мы получим данные(3 строки в данном случае) для каждого fact_id (dd,cnt).
После этого развернем (PIVOT) эту таблицу по одной строке для fact_id.
Поскольку не все даты могут быть заполнены, мы воспользуемся вторым параметром crosstab, которая определяет все значения (dd), какие должны быть в источнике. В данном случае значения от 0 до 2.
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB($$
  select fact_id
    ,extract('day' from now()-created_at)dd 
    ,count(*) cnt
  from logs
  where created_at >= (now() - interval '3 day')
  group by fact_id,dd
  order by fact_id,dd
  $$,
   $$ select n from generate_series(0,2)n
  $$
)
AS ct (fact_id int, "int_1" bigint, "int_2" bigint, "int_3" bigint)
where int_1>0





fact_id
int_1
int_2
int_3




5775
1
null
null


6122
1
1
1



Для интереса, без фильтра результат будет такой



fact_id
int_1
int_2
int_3




5775
1
null
null


6122
1
1
1


9990
null
null
1



Исходная таблица для CROSSTAB после группировки



fact_id
cnt
dd




5775
1
0


6122
1
1


9990
1
2


6122
1
0


6122
1
2



Здесь пример, где вместо now() используется константа (или параметр).
fiddle

Моих знаний хватило на сие творение. Но по мне-так оно вариация Вашего :)
И еще вопрос чей запрос, Ваш или мой, отработает быстрее...
select distinct tt.fact_id, coalesce(q1.cnt,0) as "-1d", coalesce(q2.cnt) as "-2d", coalesce(q3.cnt,0) as "-3d"
from tmp_table tt
-- сколько Fact_id было создано за вчера
left join ( select count(1) as cnt, 
                   t1.fact_id 
            from tmp_table t1 
            where t1.created_at::date = ( now() - interval '1 day')::date 
            group by t1.fact_id

          ) q1 on q1.fact_id = tt.fact_id
-- сколько Fact_id было создано за позавчера
left join ( select count(1) as cnt, 
                   t1.fact_id 
            from tmp_table t1 
            where t1.created_at::date = ( now() - interval '2 day')::date 
            group by t1.fact_id

          ) q2 on q2.fact_id = tt.fact_id
-- сколько Fact_id было создано за попозавчера
left join ( select count(1) as cnt, 
                   t1.fact_id 
            from tmp_table t1 
            where t1.created_at::date = ( now() - interval '3 day')::date 
            group by t1.fact_id

          ) q3 on q3.fact_id = tt.fact_id

where tt.created_at::date = ( now() - interval '1 day')::date


Жесть... Вы 4 раза обходите таблицу....

Тут все зависит от индексов и оптимизатора. Но, если что на звание великий ГУРУ SQL я и не претендовал :)
